# Extjs 3.3 - JsonWriter - how to save all rows and not just the dirty rows?

Tags: extjs

Extjs 3.3 - JsonWriter - how to save all rows in a grid and not just the dirty rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe do something like this before the write call -

```
myGrid.getStore().getRange().forEach(function(r){ r.markDirty();});
```